# If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$ and "$f(x)=g(x)$ iff $x=x_1$", then $f(x) \le f(x_1)$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $f(x) \le g(x)$
with equality iff $x=x_1$.

Does this mean that 
\begin{align}
f(x) \le f(x_1) \  \forall x
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

No. Take for instance $-\cos(x)$ and $x^2-1$.
You always have $-\cos(x) \le x^2-1$ and they are only equal in $0$. However, $-\cos(0)$ is a minimum (and not a maximum).
[image: plot of functions]

That would however be true if you had :
$$\forall x, y, f(x) \le g(y)$$
Which is
$$\mathrm{sup}(f(x)) \le \mathrm{inf}(g(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

No, not by far. If that were true we could take an *arbitrary* $f$ and an *arbitrary* $x_1$ and conclude that $f(x_1)$ is a global maximum of $f$, simply by defining $g(x)=f(x)+(x-x_1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

More important than the answer "no" is the advice that you should always draw a picture whenever possible:

[image]

Math isn't just a formal game on paper, it's also the intuition used to build that formal game.